# How to look at and describe the client and server communication between my browser and the Google server?

Tags: dom, webserver, client-server, html

I need to be able to look at and describe the client and server communication between my browser and the Google server.

I have downloaded net-tools but can't specifically see the communication, I've tried Wireshark but this brings too many things into it.

How can I see the communication and describe it using some sort of a web debugger tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *network* tab in Chromes developer tools or in Firebug for Firefox to see all request that are sent to a server. You could also use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Answer (score 0):

A Googler just did this for you:

https://plus.google.com/112218872649456413744/posts/dfydM2Cnepe

And a hacker news article:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5408597